# Angular bootstrap ngb-tabset add button to the rightside to align with tabs

Tags: angular7, angular-ui-bootstrap

I am using ngb tabset for tabs in my angular application. Here is the code i am using.

```
<ngb-tabset activeId="delegate-status" #tabs="ngbTabset" [activeId]="activeTab">

  <ngb-tab title="Delegate status" id="tab-delegate-status">
    <ng-template ngbTabContent class="content-container">
      <delegate-status-report></delegate-status-report>
    </ng-template>
  </ngb-tab>

  <ngb-tab title="No show" id="tab-noshow">
    <ng-template ngbTabContent class="content-container">
      <noshow-report></noshow-report>
    </ng-template>
  </ngb-tab>

</ngb-tabset>
```

I would like to have some button for eg: Export To CSV, on the right side which aligns the tab. Can anyone help me how to style this to have a button on the right side of this tabs?

[image]

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**SOLUTION 1:**

You should use `ngbNav` instead of `tabset`.`ngbNav` provides list of elements allow to put any element inside of it and functionality is as same as `tabset`.

For more info : https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/nav/overview

thanks to `ngb-nav` you can insert button element inside `li` tag and for position below css will work

```
button{
  position:absolute;
  right:15px;
}
```

Stackblitz : https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-us155y-n7tr8e?file=index.html

**SOLUTION 2**

As you need to use `ngb-tabset`, I made `button` `absolute` to be aligned anywhere as wished again and added `top:0` property to make it stick to the top. Added button element under `</ngb-tabset>`

```
button{
  position:absolute;
  right:15px;
  top:0;
}
```

Stackblitz : https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-us155y-bilsj3?file=app/tabset-preventchange.html

Comment: Thanks. But the requirement is to achieve the same using ngbtabset.

Comment: @MukilDeepthi If it worked for you,could you mark this as answer?

Answer (score 0):

if you add paragraph tag inside tabset you can add button inside the paragraph tag. You can refer to the html below

```
        <p>
          <button class="btn btn-outline-primary" type="button" name="button">Edit Profile</button>
        </p>
```

This is how my css looks like but you can change the css as per your requirement.

```
button {
   margin-top: -160px;
   right: 15px;
   border: none;
   background-color: green;
   color: white;
   height: 50px;
   position: absolute;
   border-radius: 0%;
}
```